# C# call to MS-SQL stored procedure not receiving parameters

Tags: c#

The following image is the code used to call MS=SQL stored procedure, as you can see, I am attempting to provide parameters in the request

[image: C# Visual Studio Code]

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(sqlAuth)) {

    // Open database connectionS
    connection.Open();

    // Call upon stored procedure
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("InsertSystem", connection);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ObjectID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Request.Form["objectid"].ToString();
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@SystemID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Request.Form["systemid"].ToString();
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ItemID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Request.Form["itemid"].ToString();
    int records = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    // Close database connection
    connection.Close();

}

message = "Record Saved<br /><br />";
```

The error which is returned from this is as follows:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
  HResult=0x80131904
  Message=Procedure or function 'InsertSystem' expects parameter '@SystemID', which was not supplied.
  Source=Core .Net SqlClient Data Provider
  StackTrace:
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite, String methodName)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at ServiceObjectsWebApp.Pages.ObjectInsertModel.OnPost() in C:\Users\rmcd\Desktop\ServiceObecjts\ServiceObjectsWebApp\Pages\ObjectInsert.cshtml.cs:line 46
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.ExecutorFactory.VoidHandlerMethod.Execute(Object receiver, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.<InvokeHandlerMethodAsync>d__29.MoveNext()

  This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    [External Code]
    ServiceObjectsWebApp.Pages.ObjectInsertModel.OnPost() in ObjectInsert.cshtml.cs
    [External Code]
```

Comment: Please edit your question and replace the image with text, and format your error message so the line breaks are shown correctly.

Comment: What does `Request.Form["systemid"].ToString();` show in the immediate window in the debugger?  Have you stepped through this code or are you just expecting it to work?

Comment: If @ItemId is an int, why are you setting a string value? What are the actual types that the stored proc expects?

Answer (score 0):

You're calling a stored procedure so you need to tell it that:

```
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```